# How to maximize the opened Excel file using java?

Tags: java

There is an already opened EXcel file, but is minimized.  I want to maximize that Excel sheet. I have been using open() method of Desktop Class, but sheet is not getting maximized.

Answer (score 0):

It opens file in maximized mode by default XLS reading software (office).

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {
  dt.open(new File("c:\\fileName.xls"));
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

First you maximize your XLS reading software (for e.g. office) window manually and close again and then run your program. It will open in maximized mode only.